# Dreamweaver site root below Git repository

Tags: git, website, dreamweaver

This is more of a Dreamweaver question more than anything else -- because I want to design the site and manage my git repo from within Dreamweaver. Let's say I have a Git repository setup, called `git-repo-web`.

Folder structure is as follows:

```
computer1:git-repo-web user1$ tree
.
├── .git
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
└── htdocs
    ├── bootstrap
    |   └── css
    │       ├── bootstrap-theme.css
    │       ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
    │       └── bootstrap.css
    ├── index.html
    ├── template-simple.html
    ├── template.html
    ├── terms.html
    └── whatsnew.html
```

[In Dreamweaver, my site looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onmsy.png).
If I setup the Dreamweaver site at the `git-repo-web` level, it works well with my existing git repository, but when I try to view content under htdocs it does not properly display the webpages due to the way it looks for the css files.

If I setup the Dreamweaver site at the `htdocs` level, the websites render perfectly, but it does not know about the existing git repo which is a level above htdocs.

I would like to add my Dreamweaver site at the `git-repo-web` directory level so that it recognizes the existing git repository, but I want my site root to be a directory below this, which should be `htdocs`. Is this possible?

Can I define my site at `git-repo-web` and then define a symbolic root at `htdocs`?

Comment: Obviously I could move my .git, .gitignore, .gitlab-ci.yml, README.md into htdocs and make that the site root in Dreamweaver, but I was hoping for a little more flexibility in order to keep things organized.

Comment: *"Obviously I could move my .git, .gitignore, .gitlab-ci.yml, README.md into htdocs"* - This seems to be [how Adobe thinks it should be done](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/git-support.html) . If you want to keep your current layout, you may simply need to use `git` directly from the command line or use a third-party `git` GUI client like [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) or [Git Kraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/).

Comment: You're right, I think that's the only other option. Unfortunately I coworkers who are new to git and it will be easier to use the git functions built-in to Dreamweaver so I had to resort to moving the git configuration files into htdocs. I guess I'll get over the inability to organize the way I had hoped.